# Unable to deploy javalite on heroku

Tags: java, heroku, activejdbc, javalite

**I have my procfile:**

```
web: java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.888.888.Application
```

**Connection details:**

```
Base.open("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://o3iyl77734btg.cbetxkdyhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/lt9vgms3ueidoa", "nt2qniqiuhl67", "k2dijxt3xcf9o");
```

**POM:**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.soul.seeker.Application</mainClass>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.javalite</groupId>
        <artifactId>activejdbc-instrumentation</artifactId>
        <version>${activejdbc.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>instrument</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

**Heroku logs --tail:**

```
2017-03-31T08:53:35.035665+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `java console` by user .k999@gmail.com
2017-03-31T08:59:37.504808+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-03-31T08:59:40.018376+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=8577 -jar target/*.jar`
2017-03-31T08:59:42.220679+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-03-31T08:59:42.224224+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2017-03-31T08:59:42.338167+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in target/seeker_Java_Spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2017-03-31T08:59:42.441817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-03-31T08:59:42.456928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-03-31T09:14:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user .k999@gmail.com
2017-03-31T09:14:59.771140+00:00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user .k999@gmail.com
2017-03-31T09:14:59.771140+00:00 app[api]: Deploy db9bb50 by user .k999@gmail.com
2017-03-31T09:14:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-03-31T09:15:00.343156+00:00 app[api]: Release v13 created by user .k999@gmail.com
2017-03-31T09:15:00.464317+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-03-31T09:15:03.852306+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=30122 -jar target/*.jar`
2017-03-31T09:15:06.100736+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-03-31T09:15:06.106289+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2017-03-31T09:15:06.253188+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in target/seeker_Java_Spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2017-03-31T09:15:06.338012+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-03-31T09:15:06.339425+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-03-31T09:15:06.329112+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-03-31T09:15:09.463349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=49453 -jar target/*.jar`
2017-03-31T09:15:12.032819+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-03-31T09:15:12.037084+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2017-03-31T09:15:12.129561+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in target/seeker_Java_Spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2017-03-31T09:15:12.210338+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-03-31T09:15:12.220183+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-03-31T09:15:55.312322+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="//getRecent" host=seeker-java-spark.herokuapp.com request_id=7df2a77a-8a78-43a3-874b-8ecbf394653d fwd="54.224.180.207" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-03-31T09:16:01.138972+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="//data_on_page_load?limit=4&offset=0" host=seeker-java-spark.herokuapp.com request_id=b8ff2299-bd1d-435b-bf84-e358ca9d44f6 fwd="54.224.180.207" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protoc
l=https
2017-03-31T09:17:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user .k999@gmail.com
2017-03-31T09:17:23.683130+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 4968a29 by user .k999@gmail.com
2017-03-31T09:17:23.683130+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user .k999@gmail.com
2017-03-31T09:17:24.061692+00:00 app[api]: Release v14 created by user .k999@gmail.com
2017-03-31T09:17:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-03-31T09:17:24.717686+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-03-31T09:17:27.559351+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=38303 -jar target/*.jar`
2017-03-31T09:17:29.517107+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-03-31T09:17:29.520526+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2017-03-31T09:17:29.605348+00:00 app[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in target/seeker_Java_Spark-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2017-03-31T09:17:29.727476+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-03-31T09:17:29.720959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

**heroku java console command:** Running this command shows main class not found but I have declared the procfile properly, I don't know why it is not working.

```
E:\WORKSPACE\NETBEANS_WORKSPACE\seeker_Java_Spark>heroku run java console
Running java console on seeker-java-spark... up, run.4407 (Free)
Error: Could not find or load main class console
```

Comment: Here is a page donated by community: http://javalite.io/deploying_to_heroku see if it helps!

Comment: is  your app a standalone or ActiveWeb?

Comment: @ipolevoy standalone

Comment: @ipolevoy this page `javalite.io/deploying_to_heroku` does not make sense. I am using standalone app. All that configuration is not required

Comment: ok, that page is stale, might have mistakes. However, your issue is not related to JavaLite. Try deploying a simple "Hello world" app on Heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku is trying to run your app with the command `java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=30122 -jar target/*.jar`.

Check that your `Procfile` is checked into Git by running `git ls-files`.

I don't know what `heroku run java console` is supposed to be. That's not a command I've ever seen.

Comment: `git ls-files` shows `src/main/resources/procfile` listed.

Comment: The `Procfile` needs to be in the root directory of the Git repo.

Comment: You are right. There was a procfile created by default with `$JAVA_OPTS`. Placing the procfile at root path solved the issue. Thank you so much